# Decrypt text with AWS KMS in NodeJs

Tags: node.js, encryption, aws-lambda, amazon-kms

I am trying to decrypt some text encrypted with AWS KMS using aws-sdk and NodeJs. I started to play today with NodeJs so I am a newbie with it.
I have this problem resolved with Java but I am trying to migrate an existing Alexa skill from Java to NodeJs.

The code to decrypt is:

```
function decrypt(buffer) {
    const kms = new aws.KMS({
        accessKeyId: 'accessKeyId',
        secretAccessKey: 'secretAccessKey',
        region: 'eu-west-1'
    });
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        let params = {
            "CiphertextBlob" : buffer,
        };
        kms.decrypt(params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(data.Plaintext);
            }
        });
    });
};
```

When I run this code with a correct CiphertextBlob, I get this error:

```
Promise {
  <rejected> { MissingRequiredParameter: Missing required key 'CiphertextBlob' in params
    at ParamValidator.fail (D:\Developing\abono-transportes-js\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\param_validator.js:50:37)
    at ParamValidator.validateStructure (D:\Developing\abono-transportes-js\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\param_validator.js:61:14)
    at ParamValidator.validateMember (D:\Developing\abono-transportes-js\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\param_validator.js:88:21)
    at ParamValidator.validate (D:\Developing\abono-transportes-js\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\param_validator.js:34:10)
    at Request.VALIDATE_PARAMETERS (D:\Developing\abono-transportes-js\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\event_listeners.js:126:42)
    at Request.callListeners (D:\Developing\abono-transportes-js\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at callNextListener (D:\Developing\abono-transportes-js\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\sequential_executor.js:96:12)
    at D:\Developing\abono-transportes-js\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\event_listeners.js:86:9
    at finish (D:\Developing\abono-transportes-js\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\config.js:349:7)
    at D:\Developing\abono-transportes-js\node_modules\aws-sdk\lib\config.js:367:9
  message: 'Missing required key \'CiphertextBlob\' in params',
  code: 'MissingRequiredParameter',
  time: 2019-06-30T20:29:18.890Z } }
```

I don't understand why I am receiving that if `CiphertextBlob` is in the params variable.

Anyone knows?
Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 01/07**

Test to code the feature:
First function:

```
const CheckExpirationDateHandler = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
        return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === 'IntentRequest'
            && handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.intent.name === 'TtpConsultaIntent';
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {

        var fecha = "";
        var speech = "";

        userData = handlerInput.attributesManager.getSessionAttributes();

        if (Object.keys(userData).length === 0) {
            speech = consts.No_Card_Registered;
        } else {
            console.log("Retrieving expiration date from 3rd API");
            fecha = crtm.expirationDate(cipher.decrypt(userData.code.toString()));
            speech = "Tu abono caducará el " + fecha;
        }

        return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speech)
            .shouldEndSession(true)
            .getResponse();

    }
}
```

Decrypt function provided with a log:

```
// source is plaintext
async function decrypt(source) {

    console.log("Decrypt func INPUT: " + source)
    const params = {
        CiphertextBlob: Buffer.from(source, 'base64'),
    };
    const { Plaintext } = await kms.decrypt(params).promise();
    return Plaintext.toString();
};
```

Output:

> 2019-07-01T19:01:12.814Z  38b45272-809d-4c84-b155-928bee61a4f8    INFO    Retrieving expiration date from 3rd API
>   2019-07-01T19:01:12.814Z  38b45272-809d-4c84-b155-928bee61a4f8    INFO    Decrypt func INPUT:
>   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............
>   2019-07-01T19:01:12.925Z  38b45272-809d-4c84-b155-928bee61a4f8    INFO    Error
>   handled: handlerInput.responseBuilder.speak(...).shouldEndSession is
>   not a function
>   2019-07-01T19:01:13.018Z  38b45272-809d-4c84-b155-928bee61a4f8    ERROR   Unhandled Promise
>   Rejection {"errorType":"Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection","errorMessage":"InvalidCiphertextException:
>   null","stack":["Runtime.UnhandledPromiseRejection:
>   InvalidCiphertextException: null","...

Answer (score 14, accepted):

That either means you're missing key 'CiphertextBlob' or its value is undefined.

Please checkout the value you're passing in as `buffer`.

For reference, I also added my working code example that I used.

```js
import { KMS } from 'aws-sdk';

import config from '../config';

const kms = new KMS({
  accessKeyId: config.aws.accessKeyId,
  secretAccessKey: config.aws.secretAccessKey,
  region: config.aws.region,
});

// source is plaintext
async function encrypt(source) {
  const params = {
    KeyId: config.aws.kmsKeyId,
    Plaintext: source,
  };
  const { CiphertextBlob } = await kms.encrypt(params).promise();

  // store encrypted data as base64 encoded string
  return CiphertextBlob.toString('base64');
}

// source is plaintext
async function decrypt(source) {
  const params = {
    CiphertextBlob: Buffer.from(source, 'base64'),
  };
  const { Plaintext } = await kms.decrypt(params).promise();
  return Plaintext.toString();
}

export default {
  encrypt,
  decrypt,
};
```

----- ADDED -----

I was able to reproduce your issue.

```
decrypt("this text has never been encrypted before!");
```

This code throws same error.

So if you pass plain text that has never been encrypted before or has been encrypted with different key, it throws `InvalidCiphertextException: null`.

Now I'll give you one usage example.

```
encrypt("hello world!") // this will return base64 encoded string
  .then(decrypt) // this one accepts encrypted string
  .then(decoded => console.log(decoded)); // hello world!
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried with your solution but I am getting another error "InvalidCiphertextException: null" I edited the question with the input I am using in the test. Do you know why it still fails? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I kept on getting this error in my *AWS lambda* when trying the accepted solution, using *AWS KMS* over an environment variable I had encrypted by using *AWS* user interface.

It worked for me with this code adapted from the [AWS official solution](https://aws.amazon.com/fr/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/kms-invalidciphertextexception/):

**decrypt.js**

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
AWS.config.update({ region: 'us-east-1' });

module.exports = async (env) => {
    const functionName = process.env.AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME;
    const encrypted = process.env[env];
    
    if (!process.env[env]) {
        throw Error(`Environment variable ${env} not found`) 
    }
    
    const kms = new AWS.KMS();
    try {
        const data = await kms.decrypt({
            CiphertextBlob: Buffer.from(process.env[env], 'base64'),
            EncryptionContext: { LambdaFunctionName: functionName },
        }).promise();
        console.info(`Environment variable ${env} decrypted`)
        return data.Plaintext.toString('ascii');
    } catch (err) {
        console.log('Decryption error:', err);
        throw err;
    }
}
```

To be used like this:

**index.js**

```
const decrypt = require("./decrypt.js")

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log(await decrypt("MY_CRYPTED_ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE"))
}
```

Comment: We had a similar problem - Amazon changed their API and the old decryption code stopped working.


Here's the link mentioned by @arvymetal: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/kms-invalidciphertextexception/


Bear in mind that if you have variables encrypted long time ago - you might still need code without "EncryptionContext".

Comment: Thanks for the link @PawełBadeński! Answer updated.

Answer (score 1):

1. EncryptionContext is a must for this to work.
2. Let's say the name of EnvironmentVariable is **Secret**
3. The code below reads the EnvironmentVariable called **Secret** and returns decrypted secret as plain text in the body.
4. Please see the function code posted below

'use strict';

```
const aws = require('aws-sdk');
var kms = new aws.KMS();

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    const functionName = process.env.AWS_LAMBDA_FUNCTION_NAME;
    const encryptedSecret = process.env.Secret;

    kms.decrypt({
            CiphertextBlob: new Buffer(encryptedSecret, 'base64'),
            EncryptionContext: {
                LambdaFunctionName: functionName /*Providing the name of the function as the Encryption Context is a must*/
            },
        },
        (err, data) => {

            if (err) {
                /*Handle the error please*/
            }

            var decryptedSecret = data.Plaintext.toString('ascii');

            callback(null, {
                statusCode: 200,
                body: decryptedSecret,
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
            });
        });
};
```